# How to hide spoilers inline?

Tags: support, spoilers

I can block-hide a spiler with `>!` line-prefix. How do I hide a spoiler inline?

Will it remain hidden in the summary on the question-list page?

Comment: The editing help page (http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help) only shows a block spoiler tag.

Comment: and even block-quote spoilers cannot contain multiple paragraphs (or nested blockquotes), it seems :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do inline spoilers.  It's not a feature of the Stack Exchange platform.

Sorry.